# Android reusable layouts with background causing lint overdraw error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lint, gpu-overdraw

Our android application has a theme applied at application level and this theme contains the `android:windowBackground` attribute (white color).

Now I am creating a reusable layout for a widget which will used in multiple screens. This widget also has a background (blue color) and will be used in activities which may or may not have a background applied (we have some activities with `@null` background).

Here, lint is throwing the following error/warning in this layout:

> Possible overdraw: Root element paints background with
>   a theme that also paints a background

It might be showing this error assuming application's theme for the reusable layout. Is there any way to avoid this?